# flexbox fixed width and fixed row count

Tags: css, flexbox

I made a site and using CSS flexbox for layout.

First, look at the below code that I worked.

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.wrap {
  height: 100%;
  background-color: antiquewhite;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.box {
  flex: 0 0 350px;
  height: 350px;
  background-color: aquamarine;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>
  <div class="wrap">
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

My goal is here.

1. Make every box's width fixed to 350px.
2. Regardless of browser's size, one row must have only 3 boxes. (If browser size getting bigger)
3. Do not consider case of smaller size browser.

So I defined `flex: 0 0 350px` to `.box` and `flex-wrap: wrap` to `.wrap`

But it works differently with my expectation.

Is there any way to implement fixed width flexbox?

Or solution here?

Thanks.

Comment: try using `grid` instead https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/

Comment: @Ujin Impossible with flexbox?

Comment: You can set `.wrap {width: calc(3 * 350px)}` or something like this. But `grid` is a better option for this task.

Comment: If your number of box is static you can also just wrap each "line" (3 box) in a `div`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
/* add height so that .wrap height: 100% knows what it's a percentage of */
height:100%;
}
.wrap {
  height: 100%;
  background-color: antiquewhite;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
/* add widths so that you will always have three in a row */
min-width:1056px; /* extra 6px to cater for border */
max-width:1056px;
width:1056px;
}
.box {
  flex: 0 0 350px;
  height: 350px;
  background-color: aquamarine;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>
  <div class="wrap">
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Works perfectly. Thanks.